# QGIS 2.4: Basemap.at is displayed in poor quality

Tags: wmts, qgis-2.4, austria

I have a huge problem displaying the austrian Basemap.at WMTS Service in QGIS 2.4. When I add the service, qgis logs multiple errors on failed tile requests. When I zoom into the map, it is displayed in a very poor quality (see screenshot).
 I really don't know how to fix this problem - can anyone tell me how to increase the quality of the tiles?

WMTS URL: http://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml [image: Basemap.at Scrennshot: Poor Quality]

UPDATE 1:
I tried setting the resampling methods in QGIS to Cubic/Average, as you guys advised me to and compared the result with the same zoomlevel in ArcGIS. In this screenshot you can see the result: At the same scale level QGIS just skips an entire tile level, whereas arcgis loads this level correctly. - Any other ideas? [image]

Comment: can you add the URL of the service so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: Of course: Here you are: http://maps.wien.gv.at/basemap/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: You mean you want labels for towns, cities etc (eg. "Leising") to constantly appear in a larger font when you zoom in as they did before you applied the Cubic/Average resampling?

Comment: Yes, and for example the label of the road L2091 just doesn't show up.

Comment: Other than changing the _Zoomed out_ option from _Average_ and back to _Nearest neighbour_, I'm not sure how to maintain clarity for both the map and its corresponding labels. Perhaps others may offer advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some experiments I found out that the core of this problem is related to the predefined scale levels QGIS uses. Through the slider provided at *View > Panels > Tile Scales* I could gather more information about the WMTS-Scale Levels the Basemap.at WMTS scales at.
As a next step i went to *Settings > Options > Map Tools* and replaced the scales which are defined as default with the Basemap.at scale-values through the following XML-code:

```
    <qgsScales version="1.0">
      <scale value="1:591657550"/>
      <scale value="1:295828775"/>
      <scale value="1:73957193"/>
      <scale value="1:36978596"/>
      <scale value="1:18489298"/>
      <scale value="1:9244649"/>
      <scale value="1:4622324"/>
      <scale value="1:2311162"/>
      <scale value="1:1155581"/>
      <scale value="1:577790"/>
      <scale value="1:288896"/>
      <scale value="1:144448"/>
      <scale value="1:72224"/>
      <scale value="1:36112"/>
      <scale value="1:18056"/>
      <scale value="1:9028"/>
      <scale value="1:4514"/>
      <scale value="1:2256"/>
    </qgsScales>
```

When you now reload the map, the quality of the map will be outstanding!

Comment: The Tile MapScale Plugin does the same as you found out manually.

Comment: Yes indeed, but the plugin turns out to be rather buggy with this WMTS-Service. I tried it and at least for me it doesn't work well...

Answer (score 5):

You could play around with the Resampling options in *Layer Properties* > *Style* > *Resampling*. I did a quick test and got the map to be a bit sharper by applying the following changes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your resampling suggestion works well for me.  But I have to open the Layer Properties and set the resampling to Cubic every time I open the layer from Browser Panel > Tile Server (XYZ).  Is there any way to set the cubic resampling as the default whenever the layer is loaded?

Comment: @StuSmith - I think you should ask this a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as I'm not too sure :)