# QGIS/ArcGIS Pro: WMTS-Services - different display quality

Tags: qgis, wmts

Using ArcGIS Pro (1.4) and QGIS 2.18 I discovered that both programs have a different "display-quality" of the same WMTS-Service (in my case basemap.at - the map called basemap-grey). I was surprised and checked some properties, but with no success. ArcGIS Pro seems to render it "smoother" (Screenshots attached). In both programs I tested it with the same extent at the same scale (and EPSG 3857 as data-frame SRS). In QGIS I manipulated some resampling-parameters, but without getting the same quality. 
Does someone know how to improve it ? 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is related to the pre-defined scale levels by QGIS (Settings - Options - Map Tools). Defining your own levels for basemap.at like described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/qgis-2-4-basemap-at-is-displayed-in-poor-quality?rq=1) works well. Alternatively the Tile Map Scale PlugIn does the same job.