# Shattered, rough WMTS image in QGIS 2.18.12

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, wmts

After updating QGIS i found that wmts layers are being rendered in way that makes them useless. It look's like tiles are downloaded in greater resolution and then scaled down what makes them rough and all captions unreadable.

I'm on windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Did you enable resampling in the raster options? What is the layer CRS and what is the map CRS?

Comment: Where would i do that? Is this a application setting or the layer itself?

Comment: layer settings and project settings.

Answer (score 5):

Ok some more digging with other keywords gave me the solution:

[QGIS 2.4: Basemap.at is displayed in poor quality](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/qgis-2-4-basemap-at-is-displayed-in-poor-quality)

It's related to the scale of layer in viewport. There's a plugin called "Tile map scale" which helps put map in to scale that provides best quality. You can also change qgis scales in map setting to values that ensure proper rendering.

Comment: ... and make sure to use EPSG:3875 as **project** CRS. Reprojecting the tiles will surely loose quality.